# Make an upload queue

Tags: javascript

i have a service that users upload their 3D models in my server. also, i need to have this option that users can upload multiple files at once, but the problem is that when the files number going more than 10 files, my server can't handle the process and will crash. now i want in my frontend to send files to my server one by one.
it's my function:

```
 const uploadFilesArray = async (files, id) => {
    const uploadFileAtIndex = async (index) => {
        if (index >= files.length) {
            setLoading(false);
            reloadData(id);
            return;
        }
        const file = files[index];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        await axios.post(`/app/orderfile/${id}`, formData);
        await uploadFileAtIndex(index + 1);
    };
    await uploadFileAtIndex(0);
};

const uploadFile = (files) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (!info || !info.id) {
        createOrder().then(({ id }) => {
            if (id) {
                uploadFilesArray(files, id).then(() => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    reloadData(id);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        const id = info.id;
        uploadFilesArray(files, id).then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
            reloadData(id);
        });
    }
};
```

although i tried to make queue but again it's sending all files at once to the server.

Comment: You should definitely look into fixing your server. Being able to "make it crash" with enough parallelism is a bad sign. What if *10 separate users* try this one-by-one upload simultaneously? Will it also crash?

Comment: yes. I'm working on backend codes and also improve my server configurations. but until then i should do this to reduce the failure chance.